# ~10KB of preact in final bundle with svelte-fullcalendar, why?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using https://github.com/YogliB/svelte-fullcalendar in a new Svelte project.

Analyzing my final bundle I can see there are ~10KB of `preact`. **Why?**

[image]

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4#virtual-dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sevlte-fullcalendar` [depends on `@fullcalendar/core`](https://github.com/YogliB/svelte-fullcalendar/blob/f6c0d99703feed4569e315845b60980845463004/packages/svelte-fullcalendar/package.json#L7) and `@fullcalendar/core` [depends on `preact`](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/fba064e0c4c404d5860555a772c193526036e7f6/packages/core/package.json#L9).